# Airflow not loading DAGs after upgrading to 2.4.2 or higher

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x, recursionerror

I have perfectly configured Airflow v2.4.1 application working over Docker, which when upgraded to v2.4.2 or higher fails to load DAGs. I tried every possible solutions but no use.

When playing around with `airflow.cfg` file, considering the error shown, I found out that changing  the log level from "INFO" to "ERROR" fixed the issue and all DAGs can be seen on UI also the rest is working fine.

I need to understand the root cause of the issue, so that I can fix it or raise a PR if required.

Details:
Airflow version 2.5.0
40+ DAGs
Docker image: debian11-0.0.4
Python version: python:3.9

Error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pendulum/tz/timezone.py", line 320, in _normalize
  dt = dt.__class__(
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling Python object
```

I have tried updating the Recursion limit using `sys.setrecursionlimit()` to max 100000.

Comment: Long shot but are you using timezone settings in your dags? Does the error persist when only using dags with start_dates in UTC?

Comment: Yes, the timezone is an important factor for my DAGs. 
but the error is not consistent:
sometimes the error is as:
File: "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/posixpath.py", line 143, in basename
   sep = _get_sep(p)
File: "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/posixpath.py", line 42, in basename
   if isinstance(path, bytes):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while  calling a Python object

Comment: It will probably be really hard to get to a root cause unless it can be explicitly reproducible. It might be worthwhile to [open a discussion](https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/) on the Airflow GitHub.